# RxAlamofire cannot use with URLRequest

Tags: ios, alamofire, urlrequest, rxalamofire

I'm using `RxAlamofire` to create my `observable`. I have build the `URLRequest`. normally with `Alamofire` we can use like `Alamofire.request(urlRequest)` but seem with `RxAlamofire` I can not use `RxAlamofire.requet(urlRequest)`

Here is my function

```
func createOrUpdateItem(for id: NSNumber) -> Observable<Item> {

        let testRequest = Router.top.urlRequest

        let test = RxAlamofire.request(testRequest)

    }
```

Here is the error 
[image]

Seem like `RxAlamofire` only accept parameter which are `URL` and `URLConvertible` . The strange thing is i look through RxAlamofire there are 2 method which accept both `URLConvertible` and `URLRequestConvertible`. Anyone has same same issue and how to resolve? I'm asking this because my app use `Alamofire Router` which is an enum adopt to `URLRequestConvertible`.

```
    /**
         Creates an observable of the `Request`.

         - parameter method: Alamofire method object
         - parameter url: An object adopting `URLConvertible`
         - parameter parameters: A dictionary containing all necessary options
         - parameter encoding: The kind of encoding used to process parameters
         - parameter header: A dictionary containing all the addional headers

         - returns: An observable of the `Request`
         */
    public func request(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, _ url: URLConvertible, parameters: [String : Any]? = default, encoding: ParameterEncoding = default, headers: [String : String]? = default) -> RxSwift.Observable<Alamofire.DataRequest>

    /**
         Creates an observable of the `Request`.

         - parameter URLRequest: An object adopting `URLRequestConvertible`
         - parameter parameters: A dictionary containing all necessary options
         - parameter encoding: The kind of encoding used to process parameters
         - parameter header: A dictionary containing all the addional headers

         - returns: An observable of the `Request`
         */
    public func request(urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> RxSwift.Observable<Alamofire.DataRequest>
```